# Selenium - Every page has a 'next' button but the same button doesn't always lead to the same page

Tags: java, selenium, abstract-class, extends, pageobjects

I'm doing some selenium work at the office and with some recent changes to the pages I was automating I'm trying to figure out the best way to do it. I'm not exactly sure how to explain everything but I'll give it a try.

I have a payment form with different 'steps'. Each step ask you to fill some info and they all have a 'continue' button to go to the next step. Since every pageObject shares the same button I created an abstract class with that logic and made ever page extend from that one.

Something like this (removing all the code that's not relevant to the question):

```
public abstract class AbstractPaymentPage<T extends AbstractPaymentPage> extends AbstractPageObject {

  @FindBy(id = "continueBtn")
  private WebElement continueButton;

  public AbstractPaymentPage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
  }

  public T nextStep() {
    continueButton.click();
    return this.initPageObject(getNextStepClass());
  }

  protected abstract Class<T> getNextStepClass();
}
```

And the child classes are defined like this:

```
public class PersonalInfoPage extends AbstractPaymentPage<PaymentCountryPage> {

  public PersonalInfoPage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<PaymentCountryPage> getNextStepClass() {
    return PaymentCountryPage.class;
  }

}
```

The typical usage for this is would be to call `PersonalInfoPage.nextStep()` which will click on the continue button and initialize all the webElements on the next page.

Now, this works and I'm actually pretty happy with it but it only works if the current page can tell exactly which page is coming up next. In this case 'PersonalInfoPage' knows that the next one is 'PaymentCountryPage'. But with these new changes there are scenarios in which the flow will be PageA->PageB->PageC->PageD, others that can be PageA->PageD and others could be PageA->PageC->PageD.

What do you guys think would be the best to handle something like this without ending with a ton of code duplication? Was thinking that maybe I could use generic variables instead of the actual destination class for the 'getNextStepClass' but I'm not sure how that would work.

Dunno if it's clear enough to get some help but feel free to ask anything you guys think needs more explaining and all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This complex scenario can be handled with introducing some self-loading logic into the PageObjectModel. Further more some [IoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) with the [LoadableComponent](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/LoadableComponent) and the [SlowLoadableComponent](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/SlowLoadableComponent.html) can be of a great help here. In short - let the last page know how to load itself through calling the previous page (if applicable in your domain).

Instead of

> PageA->PageB->PageC->PageD

you'll get something like

```
PageD-load->PageC-load->PageB-load->PageA
```

Clear advantage here will be the reusable received flow of control when it comes to avoid

> ending with a ton of code duplication

Comment: So what you mean is that instead of calling the first page and telling it to load the next and the next one to load the next and so forth via the "nextStep()" method should load the last page (say the "paymentSuccessPage) and pass it enough parameters so that it knows how to load itself through loading and going through the needed previous pages?.

The only problem I see is that I'm not sure I can use gets to move between pages... need to research how that is done now.